# how to bind datatable data in grid using angular

Tags: angular

this is the datatable for html:

when i debug the typescriptcode works fine no error and it stops at the binding data in gridview .in localhost there is no data in grid

in debug mode extensions:::runtime file shows some error in custom runtime binding

// Custom binding for the runtime API.

var binding = apiBridge || require('binding').Binding.create('runtime');//.Binding.create('runtime');here shows error

in extensions:::webstore

// Custom binding for the webstore API.

var webstoreNatives = requireNative('webstore');//requireNative('webstore') -this shows error

```
                        <div class="widget-body">

                            <div class="widget-body no-padding">

                                <sa-datatable [options]="{
                            data: broacasterall,
                 columns: [
                 {data:'id'},
                 {data:'broadcaster_name'},
                 {data:'broadcaster_channel_name'},

                 ],
                 buttons: [
                 'colvis'
                 ]
                 }" tableClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" >
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th data-class="expand">Id</th>
                                            <th data-class="expand">Broadcaster Name</th>
                                            <th data-class="expand">Channel Name</th>

                                     </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                </sa-datatable>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- end widget content -->
                    </div>
```

this is my typescript code for grid:
in this broadcaster response am getting fully binding data with respective columns when run the localhost it shows only grid with columns only not data

```
ngOnInit() {

        this.client_id = this.user.client_id;
        this.getBroadcasterAllGrid();
    }

  getBroadcasterAllGrid()
    {
        this.broadcasterService.getAllBroadcasters()
      .subscribe(
       (broadcasterResponse)=>{

            this.broacasterall=broadcasterResponse;


       }),
      error => this.errorMessage = <any>error;
    };
```

Comment: in debug mode i can see the data in the grid when i reload the page and see the grid means there is no data in the grid.I tried the AfterviewInit also

Comment: i got error like (WEB_PAGE context) Lazy require of webstore.binding did not set the binding field
:4200/#/admin/broadcaster:1 (WEB_PAGE context) Lazy require of runtime.binding did not set the binding field
extensions::webstore:7

Comment: i  got the solution for binding